# Jenkins Plugin SHA1 error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Am needing a little help with Jenkins plugins my instance is running through a proxy and I am pretty sure that this is the issue but I am unsure where to look in order to solve this.

When trying to install a plugin ie pipeline i get the following error in the logs

```
Failed to install Pipeline
java.io.IOException: Downloaded file /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/workflow-aggregator.jpi.tmp does not match expected SHA-1, expected 'JYbEB7D4N73SO9/QfguTWWa1il4=', actual 'yHjg4RbPTZ8WxhZnLBvcjz67tH8='
```

This is happening on all but a few plugins so it is not this plugin that is causing the issue.

I can see that the image is failing validation, but as far as I can tell it this is from the Jenkins plugin list so am not even sure why this would fail, the system log is also not very helpful.

Any pointers ?

John

Comment: Did you figure out the reason for this?

Comment: Yes I did, although I am not sure how useful this would be outside our use case. We had a security device in between us and the net which was returning a security response which was the reason for this. I think Jenkins could have helped us with this by allowing us to see the response getting to us.